# Visual Studio XAML editor ignoring key presses in the property tab

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes, when editing my `Window` in the XAML editor, the property tab just locks it self from receiving any keyboard press, I can`t even add events, I have to restart VS to work again. I still can edit using the XAML code, but the properties became read-only.

**Am I the only one having this problem? Any workaround?**

btw: *desktop WPF*

Comment: I haven't had this happen with the Properties pane, but I have had Visual Studio stop accepting keyboard input to the editor.  Usually, alt+tabbing out of VS and then back in again fixes it.  Also, the pane might lock itself while the debugger is attached.

Comment: The code editor only stopped accepting keyboard input a couple of times, but the Properties pane is almost every week. The application is stoped, but I don't know if there is some hidden process making this mess... 

Alt+Tab does nothing in this case...

Comment: Try locking and unlocking your workstation (Windows+L).  If that doesn't fix it either, you'll probably have to restart VS.  It's a pity the input processing is so flaky.  Probably a bug somewhere in the funky Win32/WPF interop they do.

Comment: Well, since this bug is a hit-miss, I need time and chance to test. Thanks. What is strange is that the WinForms property pane never had this problem.

Comment: I still have this problem in Blend 2017, but haven't experienced it yet in VS itself.  Restarting fixed it, and I'll try killing the process next time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a workaround posted by Tuan Tran 2 on 10/9/2014 at 7:36 PM on
[Microsoft Visual Studio and NET Framework Home Page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798038/unable-to-edit-properties-value-from-the-properties-window-when-developing-in-wpf):

1. Open Notepad, copy and paste this piece of code: `taskkill /f /im XDesProc.exe`
2. Save it with .bat extension.
3. Run the file by double click it whenever the property windows is not responding.

... or instead, simply kill the process `XDesProc.exe` in Task Manager.

Visual Studio will then give you the option to start again the designer. For what I read, Microsoft have knowledge of this bug, but there is no status for it yet. Hope they resolve the issue very soon.

*** UPDATE ***
@ajakblackgoat, great idea! You can add the command to Visual Studio as an External Tool:

[image: 2]]

and use it directly in the Tools Menu:

[image: 3]]

Comment: Thanks, next time that the `Property Window` don't accept my commands, I'll kill the process.

Comment: The evaluation of your solution may take a little time, this bug is almost random. Not sure what is the cause. hahaha

Comment: No problem! I had this afternoon the "privilege" of testing this and it works very nice while working on my latest WPF project. You don't need to close Visual Studio for this to work. After killing the process, the message to reload the designer pops up instantly and it lets you reload this from the same message, like it was waiting for you!

Comment: In the year 2019 Visual studio still has this bug.

Comment: End of 2020 and the bug is still going strong in VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

I had very same problem, but for me even restarting VS didnt work. I even tried restarting PC and uninstalling recently installed programs. nothing helped.

The actual problem in my case was,

**I could edit .cs files, but I couldnt edit xaml files. Only I could add line breaks in xaml.** I have spent many hours and finally found the problem was with Resharper from Jetbrains.

I had installed Resharper few days ago and after using the evaluation I have paused the licence in order to use the evaluation effectively. (In resharper menu you have pause licence option). So, when the evaluation is paused I couldn't edit xaml fils and eventually I had to resume the evaluation or uninstall resharper completely.

IMO its unfair from Jetbrains.

Comment: Sorry for the long time to answer. I have a working Resharper, with a 1 year subscription. So it can't be this.